# How to decrypt the bcrypt encrypted password?

Tags: spring-mvc, encryption, spring-security, passwords

I have written a controller ,In which I encrypted the password using BCryptPasswordEncoder like following

```
  public void setPassword(String password) {

    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();  
      String Password = passwordEncoder.encode(password);  
    this.password = Password;
}
```

Now I want to decrypt the encrypted password,So is there any class like BCryptPasswordEncoder for decrypt the password ? Please anybody help

Comment: It's not encrypted; it's hashed. It is fundamentally *not* reversible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18084693/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184328/what-is-the-difference-between-obfuscation-hashing-and-encryption?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it?rq=1